# GitLab runner is inactive

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

It appears as if a GitLab runner goes inactive after a period of time.  I followed the documentation and used mac terminal to download and register a runner with GitLab URL and token.  I got it up and running.  But I check six or so hours later and it's now inactive (no green circle any more).

I followed the directions from GitLab documentation to do a manual mac OS install of a GitLab runner:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html

If I run `gitlab-runner verify`, it becomes active again.

Do I constantly need to be re-activating the runner from command line to keep this runner active?  Unfortunately if this is the case, GitLab won't work for me as I'm working in a shared enterprise GitLab space and the runner installation was done on my personal PC.  I can't be constantly re-activating the runner from my personal PC.

I had assumed once the runner was up and active on GitLab, it was good to go.  However, it appears as if it needs to be re-instantiated on the local terminal?

Comment: Perhaps your computer went to sleep or was locked? Normally, there is no need to regularly setup the runner. What steps did you follow to setup the runner?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is I need that runner to be independent of my personal PC, since the runner is installed on a shared Gitlab project with other people. I installed it from my PC, since that was the only option given in the documentation.  I'm updating my answer to include the steps I took to setup the runner - it was a manual install.

Comment: If you installed the runner "on your personal PC", then it will only be available (green) when the corresponding service **on your personal PC** is running and polling the Gitlab server for work to do. The jobs will be executed on the computer where Gitlab Runner was installed.